# Qdrant vector db kubernetes deployment with custom context path

Tags: docker, qdrant, qdrantclient

We are trying to use Qdrant vector db for our python based API. Our kubernetes deployment expect a context-path for any deployable stuff (qdrant image in this case)

I am going through qdrant to set up a context instead of running it on root level.

I need help, if there is any way or property I can set to access qdrant dashboard/api using context path

I am going through documentation, But i could not find any config property to manage this.

Example: Running Qdrant image on local and accessing it using http://localhost:6333/ instead i want it to be accessible at http://localhost:6333/qdrant